# Number to ByteArray (Int64 BigEndian)

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

How do I convert a 64-bit number to a byte arrray in Flex/Flash? Still fairly new to flex so... Tell me there is a better way to do it than this:

```
//Some Int64 value
var n:Number = 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256;

//256 ^ 4 not working in AS?        
var i1:uint = n / (256 * 256 * 256 * 256);
var i2:uint = n - i1;

var b:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
b.writeUnsignedInt(i1);
b.writeUnsignedInt(i2);
```

Comment: As a side note, 256 ^ 4 doesn't work, because the `^` is the bitwise XOR operator. If you want to do exponentiation, you will just have to write it as a loop or implicitly such as you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this one by doing:

```
i1 * (256 * (256 << 16)) + i2
```

Answer (score 2):

Will this work?

```
var n:Number = 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256;
var b:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
b.writeDouble(n);
```

Found in [ByteArray AS3 Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeDouble%28%29)

Comment: I eventually solved this one by doing: 
i1 * (256 * (256 << 16)) + i2;